# When I try to run code in tensorlflow I get this error. How can I fix this?

Tags: tensorflow

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'abs'
```

The fixes I already tried were going into my Anaconda environment, activating it 
and running this command:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow protobuf --yes

pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu
```

Now the error is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you're installing in pip if you use Anaconda? `tensorflow-gpu` is available in anaconda. Try

```
conda remove tensorflow*
conda remove protobuf
pip uninstall tensorflow*
pip uninstall protobuf
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I tried this but it returned the following error when importing tensorflow in my code:

module 'tensorflow.python.training.checkpointable' has no attribute 'CheckpointableBase'

Comment: You could try to create a new anaconda environment as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51397065/2653663
The errors suggests that it's a broken tensorflow installation.