# how do I install tensorflow-GPU on Win 10

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

k so I have 6 1070 left over from my mining days....

So i understand all these concepts but just cant seem to install tensorflow GPU version to save my life..
I have VS studio 2015
398.82-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql.exe
python-3.7.0-amd64.exe
VSCodeSetup-x64-1.26.1.exe
cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.zip
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl

Please help i get this error

> Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   import tensorflow as tf
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
>       raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       import _pywrap_tensorflow
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 60, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg)
>   ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper
>       fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', [dirname(**file**)])
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 297, in find_module
>       raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
>   ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 54, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Users\kfprg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper
>       import _pywrap_tensorflow
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow'

Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.

I have tried about 50 times each time wiping the whole windows setup please help@?@?@@

Comment: Seem like you did not use correct `.whl` file to install tensorflow in windows environment

Comment: okay i tried devpi to remove it but it cant find right index ... is the tensorflow-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl locate in the lib folde under my python36?

Comment: okay i fount the dir.. do i just delete the directory and install another one is it that easy?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51397065/9728107     This solved it all  now i can daisy chain a few PSU and build my 6 x 1070 Machine!!!! omg Dab !!!