# Unable to uninstall Tensorflow - Folders still remain in dist-packages

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, uninstallation, tensorflow-estimator

I installed tensorflow using `sudo pip3.6 install tensorflow==1.7` (I already had tensorflow 1.6 but wanted to upgrade) however I am unable to uninstall it. I tried `sudo pip3.6 uninstall tensorflow` and it said that tensorflow is successfully uninstalled but I don't think that's true. I get the following error when I try to run a tensorflow python code (which ideally should say import error I guess)

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.training.checkpointable' has no attribute 'CheckpointableBase'

Using `sudo pip3.6 uninstall tensorflow` again only shows

> Skipping tensorflow as it is not installed.

I looked around a little and found the following folders in `usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/`

- tensorboard
- tensorboard-1.7.0.dist-info
- tensorflow
- tensorflow_datasets
- tensorflow_datasets-1.3.2.dist-info
- tensorflow_estimator
- tensorflow_estimator-1.13.0.dist-info
- tensorflow_metadata
- tensorflow_metadata-0.21.0.dist-info
- tensorflow_tensorboard-0.4.0.dist-info

It seems to be a mess. Can I go ahead and simply delete these folders? What is the correct way to removing these?

Comment: Have you already tried the solution provided here? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51390692/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-python-training-checkpointable-has-no-attrib

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to delete it manually, you can follow the below steps to do it.

- Go to the site-packages directory where pip is installing your packages in your case `usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/`.
- You should see the file that corresponds to the package you want to uninstall. Delete the file for your case `rm -rf tensor*`.
- Install your required Tensorflow version `pip install tensorflow==1.7`

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: @Red Floyd - Please Accept and Upvote if this helps you Thank you.